# Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `showheader`. If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: showheader="false"

Tags: reactjs

Got this error when everywhere PropTypes is declared as :
`showheader: PropTypes.bool.isRequired`

parent's state (Header):

```
const [showheader, setShowHeader] = useState(false);
```

example child that contains showheader props:

```
<HeaderList open={open} showheader={showheader} />
```

full error message:

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `showheader`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: showheader="false" or showheader={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with showheader={condition && value}, pass showheader={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
```

I need the current form of this declaration of props for child (showheader={showheader}) because this allows me manipulate HeaderItem component which is child of HeaderList.

Comment: what have you defined showHeader's type as , in propTypes?

Comment: showheader: PropTypes.bool.isRequired

Comment: I can see it is passed as stirng, HeaderList.propTypes = {
    open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    showheader: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
?

Comment: HeaderList.propTypes = {
    open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    showheader: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

Comment: Don't know where is the problem

Comment: dont post your edits as answers. Instead edit the existing question:)

Answer (score 0):

The code below is not showing me error, don't know why there is a problem with bool.isRequired and showheader={showheader} when showheader is a boolean.

```
<HeaderList open={open} showheader={showheader.toString()} />
```

in HeaderList.js

```
const HeaderList = ({ open, showheader }) => {
    const [items] = useState([
        { pathname: 'projects', path: routes.project },
        { pathname: 'services', path: routes.services },
        { pathname: 'about', path: routes.about },
        { pathname: 'contact', path: routes.contact },
    ]);

    return (
        <StyledList open={open}>
            {items.map(({ pathname, path, ...props }) => {
                return (
                    <StyledListItem
                        as={Link}
                        key={pathname}
                        to={path}
                        showheader={showheader}
                        {...props}
                    >
                        {pathname}
                    </StyledListItem>
                );
            })}
        </StyledList>
    );
};

HeaderList.propTypes = {
    open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    showheader: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: the problem was that I have replaced routes.project with routes.projects because routes.project doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Check your propTypes defintion. Since your passing showHeader as a boolean in the useState, Change it to boolean

```
const HeaderList = ({ open, showheader }) => {
    const [items] = useState([
        { pathname: 'projects', path: routes.project },
        { pathname: 'services', path: routes.services },
        { pathname: 'about', path: routes.about },
        { pathname: 'contact', path: routes.contact },
    ]);

    return (
        <StyledList open={open}>
            {items.map(({ pathname, path, ...props }) => {
                return (
                    <StyledListItem
                        as={Link}
                        key={pathname}
                        to={path}
                        showheader={showheader}
                        {...props}
                    >
                        {pathname}
                    </StyledListItem>
                );
            })}
        </StyledList>
    );
};

HeaderList.propTypes = {
    open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    showheader: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

Also

```
<HeaderList open={open} showheader={showheader} />
```

Comment: This is my code I have started with. I know how proptypes works and have this and this gives me an error I maintain in the title

Comment: const [showheader, setShowHeader] = useState(false); I'm pushing code to sandbox wait a second.

Comment: @KacperFaligowski yes please

Comment: I just copied the code and sandbox doesn't give me this error, but chrome does. https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-dew-5q86b

Comment: problem was in the HeaderList component. you were converting showHeader to a string. check it , I have fixed https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lumiere-tzb3p

Answer (score 0):

```
const HeaderList = ({ open, showheader }) => {
    const [items] = useState([
        { pathname: 'projects', path: routes.project },
        { pathname: 'services', path: routes.services },
        { pathname: 'about', path: routes.about },
        { pathname: 'contact', path: routes.contact },
    ]);

    return (
        <StyledList open={open}>
            {items.map(({ pathname, path, ...props }) => {
                return (
                    <StyledListItem
                        as={Link}
                        key={pathname}
                        to={path}
                        showheader={showheader}
                        {...props}
                    >
                        {pathname}
                    </StyledListItem>
                );
            })}
        </StyledList>
    );
};

HeaderList.propTypes = {
    open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    showheader: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

and

```
<HeaderList open={open} showheader={showheader} />
```

gives me an error.